# Which way is recommended to use guard let?

Tags: ios, swift, coding-style, guard

I need to check preconditions for proceeding a function in iOS/Swift.

**Option 1:**

```
guard let name = str["name"], let age = str["age"] else {
    print("name/age missing")
    return
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
guard let name = str["name"] else {
    print("name missing")
    return
}


guard let age = str["age"] else {
    print("age missing")
    return
}
```

**Which option is recommended.**

Comment: They do different things though...

Comment: @Sweeper yes they do different things. lets say the difference is insignificant then which flow is recommended. For example there is not requirement from caller to distinguish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is completely unrelated to Swift.
From a UI / UX perspective certainly the 2nd option since you can now point to the exact input field that is missing.